# Можно ли в Java сделать метод внутри метода?

Tags: java

Как сделать чтобы в методе был ещё один метод?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться: "А зачем?"

Comment: написать метод в методе нельзя. Вы можете написать два отдельных метода и вызвать один из другого.

Comment: @vp_arth данная конструкция применяется в других ЯП. Собственно вопрос топикстартера про то - есть ли она в Java. Уж применение ей найти можно, поверьте )

Comment: Функции и методы - это, мягко говоря, разные сущности.

Comment: А зачем минусовать то? Нормальный вопрос...

Comment: Идентичный вопрос на enSo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388584

Comment: @vp_arth Точно. Разные. Тем более что функций как таковых нет ни в  java, ни в вопросе.

Answer (score 4):

Можно:

- Сделать внутри метода безымянную реализацию интерфейса и использовать её метод.
- Как в прошлом пункте, только воспользоваться для этого лямбда-выражением.

Comment: Нельзя. А то что Вы тут пишите - это банальный вызов метода другого объекта. И в данном случае лучше иметь свой приватный метод.

Comment: @Sergey, формально - да. Но реально это именно то, о чём спрашивается :)

Comment: в общем то это все костыли (включая и ответы на enSO из комментария к вопросу). По факту язык не предоставляет возможности написать метод в методе и возможность такая кажется мне излишней, не смотря на уверения в комментариях в вопросе об обратном.

Comment: @pavlofff: Если это выглядит как метод и работает как метод, то почему это не метод? :)

Comment: @Sergey: А не всё ли равно, как оно реализовано под капотом?

Comment: @VladD Не сказал бы что это под капотом. А даже наоборот, выпирает из под капота. И совсем не выглядит как метод. И создавать каждый раз объект и вызвать его метод, наверное всё-таки похуже будет, чем просто вызвать свой собственный на всегда готовом экземпляре или статический.

Comment: @Sergey, но вложенному доступно замыкание, так что тут по-разному может быть, что именно проще.

Comment: @Qwertiy Толку-то от этого замыкания. Замкнутые таким образом переменные всё равно изменять нельзя, значит их можно смело передавать в метод в качестве параметров.

Comment: @Sergey, да, забыл, что не C#... Но иногда можно и без изменения обойтись)

Comment: @Sergey: Если вам нужна функциональность вложенного метода, <s>а не шашечки,</s> то вам должно быть всё равно, как именно оно реализовано. Выпирает оно или нет — вопрос доступного в языке синтаксического сахара. (Java традиционно бедна на сахар, вон даже лямбды комитет очень долго принимал.)